# vyos: how does one use an address group in a rule?

Tags: vyos

I have a (modified) configuration looking like this:
[image: screenshot of show output]

When I try to commit, however, I get an error message: "Configuration error: "OUR-SERVERS" is not a valid IP range. I really want to have individual (/32) addresses in the group that the rule references. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you just have one extra item in rule 1 (`address OUR-SERVERS`). This should fix it:

```
delete firewall name outside-in rule 1 source address OUR-SERVERS
```

Comment: So, you are saying only the "group { }" entry belongs there.

So, all I need for the rule source is:
`set firewall name outside-in rule 1 source group address-group OUR-SERVERS`

Thanks.